# commandLink action not called

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using netbeans with glassfish

In my .xhtml file, a have a link which I expect to call action `shopBean.instructorScheduleById()`

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="tooltip tour-sched" 
    rendered="#{shopBean.instructorSchedule!=null}"
    update=":dialogFormTS" action="#
    {shopBean.instructorScheduleById()}"                                             
    oncomplete="dlgTS.show()" process="@this"                                              
    ajax="true">TS<h:outputText styleClass="tooltiptext" 
    value="#{shopBean.instructorSchedule.name}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Bean file

```
@ManagedBean(name = "shopBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ShopBean {

    public ShopBean() {}

    public void getInstructorScheduleById(){
        System.out.println("hello");

    }


}
```

I looked to my Developer tools under network i see there is an ajax request but when i looked on glassfish output, there's no word `hello`

Comment: Do you place your command component inside a form?

Comment: `<p:commandLink` is inside the form, i'm really confused why clicking the link will not trigger  `getInstructorScheduleById()`

Answer (score 2):

Base on what i have learned here at stackoverflow, the `get` prefix is used for getter methods which means it must have a return value.

```
public void sum(){
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 2;
    System.out.println(num1 + num2);
}
// xhtml
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.sum()}" />
```

if you want get the value from a getter method:

```
pivate int sum;
public int getSum(){
    return this.sum;
}
public void setSum(sum){
    this.sum = sum;
}
// xhtml
<p:outputText value="#{bean.sum}" />
```

The quick solution for your problem is to remove the `get` prefix in your
bean.

Comment: Are you sure you answered the right question?